# Atlas Search Index partial match

Tags: mongodb-atlas-search

I have a `test` collection with these two documents:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("636ce11889a00c51cac27779"), sku: 'kw-lids-0009' }
{ _id: ObjectId("636ce14b89a00c51cac2777a"), sku: 'kw-fs66-gre' }
```

I've created a search index with this definition:

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "sku": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I run this aggregation:

```
[{
    $search: {
        index: 'test',
        text: {
            query: 'kw-fs',
            path: 'sku'
        }
    }
}]
```

Why do I get 2 results? I only expected the one with `sku: 'kw-fs66-gre'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During indexing, the standard anlyzer breaks the string "kw-lids-0009" into 3 tokens `[kw][lids][0009]`, and similarly tokenizes "kw-fs66-gre" as `[kw][fs66][gre]`. When you query for "kw-fs", the same analyzer tokenizes the query as `[kw][fs]`, and so Lucene matches on both documents, as both have the `[kw]` token in the index.

To get the behavior you're looking for, you should index the `sku` field as type `autocomplete` and use the `autocomplete` operator in your `$search` stage instead of `text`

Comment: Thanks Roy.

I've changed the index definition to this:
```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.standard",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "sku": {
        "type": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query to this:

```
[{
    $search: {
        index: 'test1',
        autocomplete: {
            query: 'kw-fs66',
            path: 'sku'
        }
    }
}]
```

But still getting 2 results?

Answer (score 1):

You're still getting 2 results because of the tokenization, i.e., you're still matching on [kw] in two documents. If you search for "fs66", you'll get a single match only. Results are scored based on relevance, they are not filtered. You can add `{$project: {score: { $meta: "searchScore" }}}` to your pipeline and see the difference in score between the matching documents.

If you are looking to get exact matches only, you can look to using the keyword analyzer or a custom analyzer that will strip the dashes, so you deal w/ a single token per field and not 3